# Convert a series of dates in format YYYYMMDD in a dataframe of massive data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

hi i´m trying to convert to date one field in a pd dataframe that is date but formated as YYYYMMDD

i have tried

```
pd.to_datetime('20180331').strftime('%Y:%m:%d')
```

but it doesn´t work for a full series of data, only for 1 case, i have a 500.000 lines data set so a lambda function wouldn´t be so fast.

thanks for the help

Comment: did you try using parse_dates when reading the csv?

Comment: Are you actually passing the column as an argument? The example you've shown operators on a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your column is df['col']:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format = '%Y%m%d')
```

[documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)